# How to ask about total compensation alignment before final interview round

Tags: interviewing, salary, compensation

I have just been offered a half-day final round for a job that I'm quite interested in taking.  However, in order to not waste my time or theirs, I want to make sure we are aligned on compensation beforehand.  I have a suspicion it might be below what I am making now.  How would you go about asking this? Would you not ask this at all?

I'm thinking something like this, currently:

> Hi XYZ,
>
> This is wonderful news.  I'm really excited about the opportunity as
> well.  Before we coordinate scheduling for the final interview round,
> I'd like to make sure we are aligned on compensation.  Could you
> please send over the total compensation details for this role?
>
> Thanks,
> ABC

Comment: *"I have a suspicion it might be below what I am making now"* - so, up to now in the interviewing process (final round you say) you have not discussed salary nor compensations? Also, the offer they sent states nothing about such things?

Comment: @DarkCygnus correct

Comment: I'd ask for a range rather than a specific number.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Horrible advice.  Instead it's the first thing you should ask.  If I'm looking for 400K and you're offering 250K, that isn't going to work.  Continuing is a waste of both of our time, and finding that out at the end is going to make one or both parties annoyed.  Instead in the very first communication you should feel out a ballpark range and make sure it's acceptable to both of you (or at least that it could be, based on performance in the interview).  If that means they just ghost you, that's fine-  less time wasted.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere No, its a perfectly fine time to ask about salary.  The earlier the better.  If it's a total mismatch, find out early and save everyone time.  I wouldn't press for an exact number, but you should absolutely have ballparked it if you haven't already.  Quite frankly you should do it before even the first phone call.  Half a day is a lot of time to waste if it was never going to work out anyway, especially as you're likely using PTO at your existing job to do it.  Any company not being willing to ballpark it immediately is a BIG red flag.

Answer (score 9):

Interview is a two-way process, where each party evaluates the other one based on their requirements. You should have enquired about the standard range for the position earlier in the process itself.

However, since you're already invited for a final round (i.e., invested your time to get here), it may not be very fruitful to bring up the topic for compensation alone via a cold email. If I were you, I would go ahead for the final round, and after the scheduled discussion, will talk about remuneration. Who knows, result of your interview may help you win a higher package!

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would do this over the phone:

> By the way, has the budget for this position been approved yet?
>
> May I ask what it is?